# Literally Canvas - setting canvas image

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, litterallycanvas.js

I'm wanting to set the canvas for the Literally Canvas widget to an image, similar to using the code below, but there doesn't seem to be anything in the API to do this.  Any ideas?  I can't use the code below in the literally.js file...

```
imageObj.onload = function () {
  ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
};
imageObj.src = '<?php echo $path . $image_name; ?>';
```

**EDIT:**

Code that I have now (see comment below):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.literally').literallycanvas();
  var ctx = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
  };
  imageObj.src = '<?php echo $path . $image_name; ?>';
```

Note that I am not using this code in the literallycanvas.js file and I have not modified that file.  Should I be using the code there?  If so, what about the PHP code in a Javascript file, should it be changed to a PHP file?

Comment: This isn't working for me; as soon as I start drawing, it covers over it with background color. I had to hack the "literallycanvas".js to make it work

Comment: I ended up using Fabric http://fabricjs.com/  You may want to look at this...

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that may work for many people is to set the background to transparent and place an image behind the canvas.

```
var myLC = $('.literally').literallycanvas({backgroundColor: 'transparent'});
```

You can accomplish exactly what you had in mind by drawing to the 'buffer context'. You have to edit the 'LiterallyCanvas.prototype.repaint' function and do something like:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "photo.jpg";

this.bufferCtx.drawImage(img, 90, 0, 269, 336);
```

I removed the IF that checks the 'drawBackground' boolean but I'm not entirely sure that's necessary. Using this technique, the image won't be shown until you start drawing. This is how you would access the buffer context from extrnal JS.

```
myLC[0].literallycanvas.bufferCtx.drawImage(img, 90, 0, 269, 336);
```

Note that I haven't tested this for performance but it seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

It should be working. You should get the context of the canvas first ...

```
var ctx = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
   ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
};
imageObj.src = '<?php echo $path . $image_name; ?>';
```

I tested it on the example page of Literally Canvas itself, and it's working fine.

Comment: Mmm...I have added that code to the php file which display contains the canvas, the image now displays in the canvas, but disappears when you start draw on it. I have edited my OP with the code that I have now.  The issue may be with the js code appearing before the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation now has a couple of examples related to adding images, particularly with respect to using them as backgrounds.

http://literallycanvas.com/examples/index.html